# Mean of the product of random variables

Tags: probability, multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions, expected-value

I am trying to solve a toy problem in order to better understand the solution for a harder problem about random walks.

I have formulated it as follows:
suppose $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$ is a random variable with a uniform PDF
$$p(\theta)=\frac{1}{2\pi}.$$

From this I construct two other random variables $x$ and $y$ as follows

$$x=\sin(\theta),$$
$$y=\cos(\theta).$$

I also see that they are subject to the constraint

$$x^2+y^2=1.$$

With all these definitions it is easy to calculate the moments and cumulants for $x$ and $y$ independently.

**Question:** how should I go about calculating the mean $\left< xy \right>$, or, for that matter, any of the joint moments or cumulants?

I have tried to find a joint PDF or a joint characteristic function, but I don't see how that is possible given that the two random variables are not independent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mean of $xy$ is $\frac 1 {2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \sin \theta \cos \theta d\theta= \frac 1 {2\pi} \frac 1 2 \int_0^{2\pi} \sin (2\theta) d\theta =\frac 1 {2\pi}  \frac 1 4(1-\cos (4\pi))=0$. Higher moments can also be calculated in a similar way.

Comment: Is this because I can consider $xy$ as a function of the variable $\theta$?

Comment: @ac1643 Yes, $xy$ and $(xy)^{n}$ are functions of $\theta$ for any $n$ and we know the density functions of $\theta$.